# How to push the image into DTR Docker Trusted Repository Using Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dtr

I am looking for plugin which will build the docker Image and ush it to DTR using Jenkins

- I have linux vm machine 10.1.2.3 (Build Machine) Here I want to build the Image
- The DTR repository is https://vm-some-repo.com

I am new to Docker and Jenkins

Please let me know what is the smiplest way to acchive this task.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use docker plugin for Jenkins.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

or you can configure Jenkin job to execute the shell command

- docker build . (You can get the Dockerfile from the source repository(svn, git))
- docker tag
- docker push